# Does there exist a bounding integrable continuous function?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lp-spaces, approximation

Assume we are on the space $[a,b]$ and we have a function $f\in L^1([a,b])$. Then there exists a sequence of continuous functions $\{f_n\}$ converging to $f$ in $ L^1([a,b])$. Does it also exist a continuous function $g\in L^1([a,b])$ such that $|f_n(x)|\le g(x)$?

Comment: That implies $f_n$ uniformly bounded since $g$ is bounded and that in turn implies $f$ bounded ae which is definitely not true for arbitrary integrable $f$

Comment: @Conrad Thanks, does it change the situation if we only assume that g is continuous a.e.?

Comment: What does continuos ae mean? In the context of integrable functions, there is ambiguity ae so any continuos function is technically only continuos ae but there is a unique way to solve the ambiguity in this case

Comment: @Conrad Continuous a.e., means that the set of points where the function is docontinuous have Lebesgue measure zero.

Comment: I see - that's  different than the normal usage

Comment: there is no particular reason for $\sup \int |f_n|$ to be finite which would be the case if there was any $g \in L^1$ for which $|f_n| \le g$ regardless of the continuity properties of it

Comment: @Conrad Doesn't $\sup\int|f_n|$ have to be finite since we have $L^1$ convergence?

Comment: yes - meant $\sup \max |f_n|$ so in other words $\sup ||f_n||_{\infty}$ (not $||f_n||_1$ of course) (see the counterxample in the answer below) - convergence in $L^1$ doesn't imply dominated convergence pointwise

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a  continuous function $f_n$ such that  $f_n(x)=\frac n {\ln n }$ on $(0,\frac 1 n)$, $0$ on $(\frac 2 n , 1)$  and linear in $[\frac1  n , \frac  2 n]$. In this case $f_n \to 0$ on $L^{1}(0,1)$ but there is no integrable function $g$ such that $f_n \leq g$ a.e. for every $n$. Proof: On $(\frac  1{n+1}, \frac 1 n)$ we have $g(x) \geq \frac n {\ln n }$ so we get $\int_0^{1} g(x) dx \geq \sum_n \frac n {\ln n } (\frac  1n -\frac 1 {n+1})=\infty$.

Comment: Thank you. Here you have a particular sequence of functions converging in L1, but you could also have chosen the sequence of functions to be identially zero. Could the proposition be said another way, does there exist a sequence of continuous functions converging in $L^1$ to f, where there also exist a bounding continuous a.s. function in $L^1$?

Comment: I asked the new question here if your are interested: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3757027/does-there-exist-a-sequence-of-continuous-functions-and-a-dominating-continuous